# Datatables function "fnDeleteRow" can't delete row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/daxm1vr3/2/) to delete a row in datatables.

```
$(".deleteRow").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
    var nRow = row[0];
    table_reach_condition_appoint_datatable.dataTable().fnDeleteRow(nRow);
});
```

This code is the core code in js about delete row with datatables.

I have imported the related js in my html.

When I click the link to delete, you can see the picture:
[image]

It is no effect,where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
table.row( $(this).parents('tr')) .remove().draw();
```

or

```
table.row($(this).closest("tr")) .remove().draw();
```

Comment: have used like this  
 table_reach_condition_appoint_datatable.row( $(this).parents('tr')) .remove().draw();

Comment: @MadFrog, if you are using dataTable() you can use the API by     `table_reach_condition_appoint_datatable.api().row( $(this).parents('tr')) .remove().draw();`

Comment: @venkat.yerr Thank you!It is helpful!